# Usando Flash Professional, como importar classes de um arquivo ActionScript?

Tags: classes, actionscript-3, objetos, flash, importação

Em meu projeto tenho a classe ListLoader, responsável na interpretação de uma lista e no upload arquivos descritos na mesma.
  Meu objetivo e poder salvar, esta e outras classes, em um arquivo de extensão ".as" e poder importar-lo tanto em meu projeto atual, quanto em outros.
 É importante citar que, esta classe não é um objeto de palco.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O sistema de importação do Flash (no caso do ActionScript 3.0) funciona procurando em duas pastas e suas subpastas (você pode adicionar mais pastas nas preferências do projeto, na seção de bibliotecas): A pasta onde está a `Main` e a pasta onde o compilador está instalado.
No seu caso, basta criar uma pasta, por exemplo, `ClassesAuxiliares` e colar o arquivo `.as` lá dentro.
Para importar utilize a seguinte sintaxe:

```as3
import ClassesAuxiliares.MinhaClasseAuxiliar;
```

De uma forma genérica, você fornecerá o caminho de onde está a classe.

Comment: Não entendi direito ,1°Quais são as classes de importação automática é usa localização? no caso são nelas ficam os arquivos que são carregados para todos projetos?, 2° Alem das pastas anteriores tem as minhas sub-pastas, que eu gerencio? e nelas os arquivos são usados apenas pelo projeto em que foi configurado a sub-pasta?

Comment: Não entendi a sua dúvida. Mas as pastas que já são adicionadas automaticamente para procura são a pasta do projeto e a pasta onde está o compilador (e todas as subpastas dessas duas pastas). Já para adicionar mais pastas que serão verificadas, você deve adicionar o caminho delas nas preferências do projeto.

Answer (score 1):

As classes importadas do ActionScript precisam estar empacotadas com o caminho do diretório onde elas estão salvas. Isto é pré-definido na declaração do pacote da classe dentro do código do seu AS.

Vamos supor que possuo uma classe chamada **Example** que faz parte do pacote **examples**, logo o código do pacote dentro da classe seria:

```
package examples { //PACOTE DA CLASSE
     public class Example {
          public function Example() {
              //Construtor
          }
     }
}
```

E o caminho da classe no diretório seria **raizdoseuswf/examples/Example.as**.

Para utilizar esta classe, você precisa importá-la para seu projeto/classe utilizando o caminho e o nome da mesma no início do código. Veja abaixo:

```
import examples.Example;
var novoExemplo:Example = new Example();
```

[Este vídeo](http://vimeo.com/7267301) pode te ajudar bastante.